# Fixed defined color in the diagram

Tags: oracle-apex

In a bar chart I display two values. OK and Not_OK. Only the bar of OK is displayed in red and the bar of Not_OK in green. I have the feeling APEX assigns color by chance. Can I define the color for the respective value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the color in the series of your chart.  I have built a sample application you can see [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/adptest/r/ej-testing/bar-chart-color-test).

[image: chart screenshot]

If both bars are defined in the same series, you can create a column for the color, then reference that column in Color field of the series. If the two bars are defined in different series, you can use the same method, or select a color to use for that series.

[image: APEX series definition]